# Plotting Classification data using NP array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a classification data where the X field is a 2-dimensional array with 12 column as features. How can this be plotted in a graph where the first 3000 fields belong to class 1 and the other 9000 data belongs to class 2 data. The data looks something like this.

`[[4.860e+02 1.400e+01 4.700e+01 ... 1.500e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.897e+03 1.000e+01 3.850e+02 ... 1.200e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.330e+02 1.500e+01 4.700e+01 ... 1.000e+01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 ...
 [8.700e+01 1.000e+00 1.000e+01 ... 9.800e+01 1.300e+01 1.000e+01]
 [5.700e+01 1.000e+00 7.000e+00 ... 9.000e+01 1.700e+01 2.600e+01]
 [1.200e+01 0.000e+00 2.000e+00 ... 9.600e+01 7.000e+00 1.200e+01]]`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand your problem from the info you provided. Please add more information so it is more clear. I can't put this as a comment because I don't have enough reputation, sorry.

So I'll post an answer alongside. As I understand your question you have a (9000 x 12) numpy array, where the 12 columns are variables and the 9000 rows are observations? And you want to divide the data into 2 classes and plot them in the same plot with different color/linestyle/etc.?

If you want to assign categoricals ("Classification variables") to your array, `pandas` would be the optimal module to do so. If you want to do it solely with numpy I would use something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
arr = np.random.randn(9000, 12)

# Split data
class_a = arr[:3001, :]
class_b = arr[3001:, :]

# Plot both classes in same plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(class_a[:, 0], class_a[:, 1])  # Choose columns you want to plot
ax.plot(class_b[:, 0], class_b[:, 1])
```

If you use 2 separate `plt.plot` calls, matplotlib will automatically use a new color.
An approach with `pandas` and `seaborn` would extend the `arr` variable:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

df['Class'] = 'A'
df.Class[3001:] = 'B'  # Hacky solution, but got no time to elaborate

sns.lineplot(data=df, x=0, y=1, hue='Class')
```